# How to publish many MXD files in ArcGIS Server 10.1 automatically?

Tags: arcgis-server, map-service

How to publish many mxd files in ArcGIS Server 10.1 automatically?

I have about 60 mxd files and I want to publish them automatically. 
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Btelliot, your code also works 10.2!
There is obviously a need to define some details concerning the service, but this is an amazing starting point!!! 10X

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you can use arcpy for publishing your mxd files.

for listing your mxd files use os.walk :

```
import os
import arcpy

path= r"c:\path"
for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(path):
  for fl in files:
     if fl.lower().endswith(".mxd"):
       mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(os.path.join(path, fl))
       print mxd.filePath
```

and then go this way:

**1.** AnalyzeForMSD() function ([info](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s300000013000000)): Analyzes map documents (.mxd) to determine sources for potential suitability and performance issues when converting a map to a map service definition (MSD) file.

Example:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Project\ReadyForMSD.mxd")
analysis = arcpy.mapping.AnalyzeForMSD(mxd)
```

**2.** ConvertToMSD() function ([info](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s300000034000000)) : Converts a map to a map service definition (MSD) file.

Example:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Project\ReadyForMSD.mxd")
msd = r"C:\Project\Output\Project.msd"
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "County Maps")[0]
arcpy.mapping.ConvertToMSD(mxd, msd, df, "NORMAL", "NORMAL")
del mxd, msd
```

**3.** PublishMSDToServer() function ([info](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s300000021000000)) : Publishes an existing map service definition (MSD) file to a designated ArcGIS Server.

Example:

```
import arcpy
msd = r"C:\Project\Project.msd"
arcpy.mapping.PublishMSDToServer (msd, "http://<MyServer>/arcgis/services", 
              "<MyServer>", "MyMapService", "MyMapServiceFolder", ["WMS", "KML"])
```

the last thing is you should do that merge all funcitons for your needs. actually there is a tutorial which can help u [here](http://geochalkboard.wordpress.com/2010/11/15/use-arcpy-mapping-to-publish-map-documents-to-arcgis-server/) about *Use ArcPy Mapping to Publish Map Documents to ArcGIS Server*. it is similar to my documentation...

To summarize(image is from link which i give above):

[image: arcgis]

i hope it helps you...

Comment: Its will by work with ags 10.1? In 10.1 is *.sd instead of *.msd.

Comment: yes this is for 10 but you can update the new arcpy for 10.1...

Comment: Thanks Aragon, this was very helpful! Just finished auto-publishing over 130 MXDs. :)  Just for posterity, the 10.1 workflow is: `arcpy.mapping.CreateMapSDDraft` -> `arcpy.StageService_server` -> `arcpy.UploadServiceDefinition_server`

Answer (score 5):

if you want do it in c# you can see in my blog: 
http://nicogis.blogspot.it/2012/10/ags-101-restful-administrative-api.html

for conversion mxd -> msd you can use python called from c#

Answer (score 4):

Aragon has a great answer, but unfortunately it doesn't work for ArcGIS / ArcServer 10.1.

The new method I just tried is based off of the ArcGIS 10.1 help.  You can find the link to the help file here:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s30000006q000000

Here is how I used the code to publish MXDs based on a specified folder:

```
#import modules
import arcpy, sys, os, string

#specify folder containing MXDs
inFolder = raw_input("Please enter folder containing 10.1 MXDs to Publish to ArcServer: ")

#specify connection File Path
connectionFilePath = r'C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.1\ArcCatalog\<your connection file location.ags>'

#look in folder for mxds
MapPath= []
MapFolder = os.listdir(inFolder)
for file in MapFolder:
    fileExt = os.path.splitext(file)[1]
    if fileExt == ".mxd":
        MapPath = os.path.join(inFolder, file)
        file = MapPath.strip('\'')
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(file)
        base = os.path.basename(file)
        serviceName = base[:-4]
        SDDraft = file[:-4] + ".sddraft"
        sd = file[:-4] + ".sd"

        #Create Map SD Draft
        print "\n" + "Publishing: " + base
        analysis = arcpy.mapping.CreateMapSDDraft(mxd, SDDraft, serviceName, "FROM_CONNECTION_FILE", connectionFilePath, "False", <Service Folder Name>,  "None", "None")

        # stage and upload the service if the sddraft analysis did not contain errors
        if analysis['errors'] == {}:
            # Execute StageService
            print "Staging Service"
            arcpy.StageService_server(SDDraft, sd)
            # Execute UploadServiceDefinition
            print "Uploading Service Definition"
            arcpy.UploadServiceDefinition_server(sd, connectionFilePath)
            print "Publishing " + base +" succeeded" + "\n"
        else:
            # if the sddraft analysis contained errors, display them
            print analysis['errors']
```

There might be a simpler way to use this code, but it works for me.  Hope this helps.